Linear combination of vectors with Gaussian coefficients
This is a cross-posted question of here. Since I have trouble of formulating the problem formally, I wish to receive some feedback/help from Stackexchange community.
My question
Motivated by a simple fact that any vector is equal/parallel to itself, thus, clearly, if we take $k$ unit vectors $v_i$ on a unit circle, $$\cos\theta=\left\langle \sum_i^kv_i,\sum_i^kv_i\right\rangle=\frac{\sum_i^kv_i\cdot \sum_i^kv_i}{\|\sum_i^kv_i\|_2^2}=1$$

Now, create a new vector $a_iv_i$ where $a_i$ is $N(1,\sigma^2)$.
As we can see, this new vector is obtained by keeping its direction, but stretch $v_i$ with size $a_i$, whose expectation is $1$, and variance $\sigma^2$. In other words, $a_iv_i$ is a random vector that, $\mathbb Ea_iv_i$ is the original vector $v_i$.
Consider $$U_1:=\sum_i^ka_iv_i \text{ and } U_2:=\sum_i^kb_iv_i$$ where $a_i,i\in[k]$ and $b_i,i\in[k]$ are iid $N(1,\sigma^2)$. Clearly, $\mathbb E U_1=\sum_iv_i$ and $\mathbb E U_2=\sum_iv_i$ are in parallel.

Can we still expect that the two vector is in parallel (nearly) with
high probability? Explictly, I am having trouble how to formulate the problem even. I posted some experiments below which provides intuitions.

I tried initially, I thought this is simply a "concentration" problem. We just need to compute how much $\cos\theta:=\frac{\sum_i^ka_iv_i\cdot \sum_i^kb_iv_i}{\|\sum_i^ka_iv_i\|\|\sum_i^kb_iv_i\|}$ concentrates to $1$, then we know how $\cos\theta$ is deviated from $1$ below, with high probability. However, later I found the expectation $\mathbb E\cos\theta\neq 1$, which seems that  this isn't the appropriate way to think about it.
Experiment 1 Generate $k=50$ vectors $v_i$, $i\in[50]$. Generate $\sum_i a_iv_i$ and $\sum_i b_iv_i$, for $a_i,b_i\sim N(1,\sigma^2)$. The experiment tells that: for $U_1,U_2$ nearly align, we would need a decreasing function $\sigma^2$.  Matlab Code.
(1) $\sigma=0$. Clearly, the vectors align.
(2) $\sigma=k^{-1}$. In this case, the length of $a_iv_i$ doesn't exceed $1$ due to the small $\sigma$. And, $a_iv_i$ $ b_iv_i$ are highly aligned.

(3) $\sigma=k^{-1/3}$.

(4) $\sigma=k^{-1/5}$ see picture
Experiment 2 After experiment 1, I feel that if we constraint angles to be in an small arc, instead of the whole unit circle, we can have better tolerance of $\sigma^2$, in a way that even $\sigma^2$ is increasing function of $n$, the two vectors are still aligned nearly.
Generate $k=50$ vectors $v_i$, $i\in[50]$ in $[-\pi/4,\pi/4]$. Generate $\sum_i a_iv_i$ and $\sum_i b_iv_i$, for $a_i,b_i\sim N(1,\sigma^2)$. Below, $\sigma=k^{1/4}$.

In fact, because of the gaussian variance $\sigma^2$, some vectors are flipped to opposite directions, but since $\sigma^2$ is not very large, only small fractions of vectors are flipped (as we can see from the right two figures), thus the sum of all vectors (including unflipped and flipped ones) still pointing towards the right.
I hope my problem is clear, and any comment/insight/suggestion would be appreciated.

It might be worth looking at a particular case to get a feel of what is happening, for example with $k=2$ orthogonal unit vectors and $\sigma^2=1$.  My simulation (which may have errors) suggests your $\cos \theta$ will range between $-1$ and $1$, with an expectation of just above $0.5$ (it must obviously be below $1$) - the peak of the distribution is at $1$ and there is a small secondary peak at $-1$.  Increasing $\sigma^2$ or the angle between the two unit vectors seems to reduce the expectation, while reducing them seems to increase it.

@Henry I added experiments in my post. It looks like if $\sigma$ is a number that decreases to zero with certain speed, the angle is near zero. But I am having trouble how to prove it, and find the exact relation between $\sigma$ and angle $\theta$.

OK - you are looking at many more unit vectors than I am (your post seems to use both $n$ and $k$ for this number).

Your edit says $a_i,b_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ though earlier this was $a_i,b_i\sim N(1,\sigma^2)$

@Henry sorry, it is a typo, it is $N(1,\sigma^2)$.

@Henry yes, $n$ and $k$ are the same, I will change it to $k$
